# Replace text with another

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace

I would like to replace a string with another string. For example: 
I would like to change the following text:

```
"listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']"
```

**to the following text**

```
"listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:40', '[::1]:40']"
```

I tried this command:

```
sudo sed "s#listen_addresses \= \['127\.0\.0\.1\:53'\, '\[\:\:1\]\:53'\]'#listen_addresses \= \['127\.0\.0\.1\:40'\, '\[\:\:1\]\:40'\]#g"
```

and I got this result:

*input*: `listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']`

*output*: `listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you only need to escape `[ ` and `]`, and in first part of replacement.

Comment: You're not "replacing any string", you're replacing a *very specific string* -- the port at the end of a listen_address configuration list in a file. Understanding exactly what you want leads people a long way towards the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as explain in comment, only `[` and `]` are to be escaped

```
echo "listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']" |
sed -e "s#listen_addresses = \['127.0.0.1:53', '\[::1\]:53'#listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:40', '[::1]:40'#"
```

which give

```
listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:40', '[::1]:40']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sed "/^listen_addresses = \['127\.0\.0\.1:53', '\[::1\]:53'\]$/s/53/40/g" file
```

---

- Searches for the *exact* string `listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']`
- If the string matches `s/53/40/g` will replace all occurences of `53` with `40` (but only in the matched line)

---

Example output:

```
$ cat file
listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']
listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.2:53', '[::1]:53']

$ sed "/^listen_addresses = \['127\.0\.0\.1:53', '\[::1\]:53'\]$/s/53/40/g" file
listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:40', '[::1]:40']
listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.2:53', '[::1]:53']
```

As you can see, an exact match is needed to perform the replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed s/":53'"/":40'"/g <<<"listen_addresses = ['127.0.0.1:53', '[::1]:53']"
```

do something close to you asked. But I agree with comment of @Jeff Schaller!

From your question nobody can recognize why do you simply do not it by hand? What is the text from which you get your lines, how they differs each other? what variants should be covered by regex?

`sed` is good for replacing but for electing the coresct line the `grep` is better.